# Use all images from my default store on my new store view

Tags: php, image, shell, magento

I have a new store view and i've updated all the products using the magento admin: `**Manage Products > Select all > Update Attributes**` and then selecting the new store. Now that all my products are affiliated with my new store view i'm having a problem with all my images. On the front end it shows all placeholders. In the admin panel when i click on a product and then images.. it may have images but it's not selected to use base image, small image or thumbnail.

Is there a way to update all images on my new store view to use the default store view main images?

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Attach_Default_Store_Images Extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {

    public function run()
    {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $productFrom = $product->setStoreId(1)->getImage();
            $productTo = $product->setStoreId(13)
            ->setImage($productFrom)
            ->setSmallImage($productFrom)
            ->setThumbnail($productFrom);
            echo "Images Updated\n";
            $product->save();
   }

        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
        echo "Image Cache Cleared\n";

    }


    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f cache.php -- [options]
        php -f cache.php -- clean

  clean             Clean Old Cache
  help              This help

USAGE;
    }
}

$shell = new Attach_Default_Store_Images();
$shell->run();
```

Run a shell script with above?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **magmi** for this , just export the products CSV from magento admin, and re-import the required fields like SKU, image, small_image and thumbnail through **magmi** and it will do your work very fast and easily.

Comment: I'd rather not use magmi, but i'm familiar with this option.

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
    if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
    if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this and run it inside of /shell?

Comment: my new store view @faizanbeg is 13.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in your magento root:

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app('default');
    $storeId = 0;
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId));

    $from_id    = 1 // product id from;
    $to_id  = 1000 // product id to;
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('gteq'=>$from_id))
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('lteq'=>$to_id));

    foreach ($products as $product) {   

     if (!$product->getImage()) continue;
    if (!$product->getSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
    if (!$product->getThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage()); 
    $product->save(); 

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Abhinav Sing, my new store view that i want all the images attached to is 13.